# Aws ecs to consistent read/update postgres record

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I am looking for standards to follow so that aws docker ecs service will read or write the consistent data/record in postgres. When there are two or more ecs services of same image running simultaneously, I want the read/write to be consistent. Please let me know.

For each record in the postgres table, there is corresponding s3 file as well. This s3 url is actually stored in one of the column as well. Is there a way to use some lock file kept under this s3 location, so that the lock file would provide a consistent read/write?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This might be a silly question, does aws postgres support record level lock? Thanks

Comment: I found this [row-locking](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/10/16/postgresql-locking-part-1-row-locks/) mechanism which might help to avoid the dirty read.